# Вычисление поэлементного произведения изображений через свертку в частотной области

Tags: matlab, фурье

Есть теорема, которая говорит, что произведение двух функций в пространственной области есть их свертка в частотной (с коэффициентом 1/(2*PI)).
Для начала пытаюсь реализовать пример согласно этой теореме в Matlab`е следующим образом:

```
A=[1 2 5 3; 8 9 6 7; 5 0 2 4; 1 0 4 5];
B=[8 9 3 4; 9 8 2 0; 7 7 9 8; 1 2 8 2];
mult = A.*B;

Af = fft2(A);
Bf = fft2(B);

mult2 = conv2(Af*.Bf);
```

Собственно вопрос: размер mul2 больше чем размер матрицы mult, и значения не совпадают, в чем причина? И еще вопрос: в C++ я свертку вычисляю с помощью скользящего окна, т.е. между двумя изображениями матрица свертки будет размера (W1 - w2)x(H1 - H2), где W1, H1 - размеры первого изображения, а W2, H2 - соответственно второго. Так как же получить результат, размерность которого была бы такой же размерности как и результат поэлементного умножения двух двумерных массивов (в случае с массивами A и B 4x4).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить центральную часть свёртки нужно в функцию [conv2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) передать дополнительный аргумент 'same':

```
mult2 = conv2(Af, Bf, 'same')
```

Также после свёртки не забываем вернуться во временную область [ifft2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft2.html).